# will vectors stay contiguous after swapping?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, swap, contiguous

Will vectors stay contiguous after swapping two elements?

PS: Regardless of the answer what might be, How can we really be sure? if that's possible.

Comment: You mean "contiguous"? `std::vector` is designed to hold contiguous elements, how would it not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can we really be sure?

For most people the guarantee from the standard should be sufficient.

> [n3337, 23.6.6.1] The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is
>   a vector where T is some type other than bool, then it
>   obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size().

You can do this is in a hacky way.

```
template<typename T>
void PrintVectorElements(vector<T> C){
   auto startPtr = C.data();
   for (auto x = C.begin(); x != C.end(); ++startPtr, ++x){
        assert(*startPtr == *x);
        assert(&(*x) == startPtr); // take this line with a pinch of salt
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swapping two elements just copies the data from one to the other and viceversa, the memory allocated remains the same, so, yes, it remains contiguous.

Comment: But if you are aware of the possible memory framentation you should write your own memory allocator [link](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/c-custom-memory-allocation-r3010)

Comment: How could swapping two vector elements possibly cause fragmentation?

Comment: I was not talking about that swapping two vector produce memory framentation, I was talking about that I you care about the memory of your program it is interesting to create your own memory pool

Comment: Yes, but that's as relevant to the question (and answer) as the fact that if you want sweet tea you can put sugar in it.